# Как заполнить трехмерный массив с помощью BufferedReader?

Tags: java

Возник такой вопрос: есть входные данные - размерность массива, допустим x y z, нужен заполнить массив этой размерности, данные поступают в следующем порядке, x блоков по y*z, между каждым блоком пробел, вот что у меня получилось:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    static int i;
    static int j;
    static int t;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));

        i = s.nextInt();
        j = s.nextInt();
        t = s.nextInt();

        int[][][] A = new int[i][j][t];
        int[][][] S = new int[i][j][t];

        for (int x = 0; x < i; ++x) {
            for (int y = 0; y < j; y++) {
                String[] mass = reader.readLine().split(" ");
                for (int z = 0; z < t; z++) {
                    S[x][y][z] = Integer.parseInt(mass[z]);
                }
            }
        }

        print(S);

        A[0][0][0] = S[0][0][0];

        for (int x1 = 0; x1 < i; ++x1) {
            for (int y = 0; y < j; ++y) {
                for (int z = 0; z < t; ++z) {
                    A[x1][y][z] = S[x1][y][z] - sum(A, x1, y, z);
                }
            }
        }

        // print(A);
    }

    static int sum(int[][][] A, int i, int j, int t) {
        int rez = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x <= i; ++x) {
            for (int y = 0; y <= j; ++y) {
                for (int z = 0; z <= t; ++z) {
                    if (x != i || y != j || z != t) {
                        rez += A[x][y][z];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return rez;
    }

    static void print(int[][][] a) {

        for (int x = 0; x < i; ++x) {
            for (int y = 0; y < j; ++y) {
                for (int z = 0; z < t; ++z) {
                    System.out.print(a[x][y][z] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Как мне все это дело правильно организовать?

Comment: Дебаг не помагает?

Comment: А что значит "правильно организовать"? Чего Вы хотите-то?

Comment: Вопрос относительно первого цикла, где заполняется массив S.

Мне нужно заполнить массив x блоками по y*z, где между каждым блоком будет пробел, а readLine() нервно реагирует на лишние пробелы

Comment: Так замените их replace пробелы